# I have built the classification model using tensorflow estimator after saving the model , when converting it into tensorflow lite it shows an error

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

```
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("/content/drive/MyDrive/tensorflowtest/1618754788") #path to the SavedModel directenter code hereory
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
 tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops.
]
```

> Model Saves Without Any Error

```
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

> When i execute this line I get this Exception

```
  ConverterError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert.py in toco_convert_protos(model_flags_str, toco_flags_str, input_data_str, debug_info_str, enable_mlir_converter)
    295       return model_str
    296     except Exception as e:
--> 297       raise ConverterError(str(e))
    298 
    299   if distutils.spawn.find_executable(_toco_from_proto_bin) is None:

ConverterError: <unknown>:0: error: loc("head/predictions/str_classes"): 'tf.AsString' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
<unknown>:0: error: failed while converting: 'main': 
Some ops in the model are custom ops, See instructions to implement custom ops: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_custom 
Custom ops: AsString
Details:
    tf.AsString(tensor<?x1xi64>) -> (tensor<?x1x!tf.string>) : {device = "", fill = "", precision = -1 : i64, scientific = false, shortest = false, width = -1 : i64}
```

> I tried Using tensor flow nightly but error still remains
> I am trying to build a classification model using tensorflow as then i want to convert it into tensorflow lite for Android App
> if you have any other appproch without converting into tensorflow lite that would be acceptable too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TF select option in the TFLite product does not allow `tf.AsString` op yet. For such cases, you can report the feature request at [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues).

The above op isn't included the TF select's allowed list, which can be fixed by adding the relevant code like this [commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/621224c8422d1cdb33ceddba7f8c694cb69f07bb). It would be great if you can create a such PR.

---

The [fix](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/3d6647c90a4d5f809966601248e220014d64054f) is submitted and the AsString op will be available through the TF select option since the tomorrow's TensorFlow nightly version.